# Podio Item task_count not passed in Filter items

Tags: api, count, task, podio

in the ruby as php library I see the task_count being referenced as an attribute however when doing the API call (only tested in ruby) I always get task_count = null.

Can this be fixed? Or another way to quickly get the task count for a larger amount of items?

Comment: Can you please provide example of your request and response that you are getting? Also, it would be easier to answer your question if you share sample source code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a call to get tasks.

https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/get-task-count-38316458
Its returning perfect[image] count for me. I have done the same with Java SDK.It take ref type and id as a parameter. 
In your case reftype = Item and id = item id.

Let me know if it helps or you need more details.

Comment: Hi Priya, thanks for the response. I know there are separate API calls to pull in the tasks. My goal is actually to quickly get a task count for multiple items. That's why I'm using the Item.filter. If there is another API call that gives me that same info, that's fine too. But with yours I'll have to do 1 API call per item which is too expensive